# AI difficulty in Starcraft is not behaving as expected

Tags: starcraft-2

I will start by saying that I have only been playing this game for two days. At first "Medium" was very hard for me because the enemy was ripping me apart. This was especially true about "Hard" when I was able to cheese my way there, I was torn up by the computer that built a massive army and annihilated my troops.

[image: Screenshot of message showing difficulty promotion]

Right now, as of this morning, the AI is not doing *anything*. There is hardly any fight at all. I send my troops in, meet with a minor resistance and topple their base like a house of cards. I am not bragging about my ability, I am wondering if there is a mysterious bug messing up my game cause I want challenge and I want to learn. I don't want to waste my time in 1v1 until I feel I mastered the macro and micro vs AI so... is there any way to check if the AI is working as expected and if not, report it as a bug so I can get it fixed?

Comment: Are you playing custom maps or using the Versus AI option?

Comment: Also, what is the current difficultly you are playing vs that is **too easy**.

Comment: Just to comment on this "I don't want to waste my time in 1v1". You would not be losing your time if you played versus real players, the matchmaking will put you against opponent of your level and you will learn a lot. Playing against AI has its limits, depending on the difficulty they push at the same timing everytime, therefore you learn nothing about mindgames.

Comment: @Shunwoo I'm also a pretty new player (about 1 month) and my experience with the pvp matchmaking has been poor. I know I'm not good and don't expect to win, but the few times I used the matchmaking I got paired with players who CLEARLY outclassed me. I'm not sure I was reading his rank correctly, but I think it said top 50 something or other. Is there some place I can read more information on how SC2 does the matchmaking?

Comment: @user137 top 50 in his league (which can be bronze, the lowest), not in the world/region, don't worry ^^ and if you do at least ten games the games will be fair, their system is not new, and it works really well, don't worry.

Comment: @dphil I was playing **harder** against Zerg, and the Enemy base was in very poor shape. They did not expand or build a lot of crucial buildings. I personally think it was a bug. I don't mind much cause **harder** worked well after that. Hard as become too easy at this point naturally I suppose.

Comment: @Shunwoo , you might have misunderstood, like I said, I like 1v1 it's just that I feel I owe the other players to master macro and micro before I move on to that level. I think that If I make it to Elite vs AI than I'd be ready for real players. I know there is a lot to be learned from real players, I just don't know if I could express myself in the game until my epm and macro is in a sufficient level.

Comment: @Sorean I was using matchmaking and picking vs AI.

Comment: @Zehelvion the fastest way to learn the game is by playing real players, however sometimes it is quite stressful because of how much cheese you will encounter. You should definitely not wait until you master elite then moving to pvp. You should go pvp now because you can't really learn that much from AI. Go pvp for a few games and watch your own replay to see how you have won/lost. You can learn a lot from replays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**is there any way to check if the AI is working as expected and if not, report it as a bug so I can get it fixed?** You can report a bug on the SC2 bug reporting forums which is found here: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/13440/

Your goal though seems to be that you simply want to practice vs opponents at your level.  The actual 1v1 matchmaking system was built exactly for this.  You may run into several games where opponents are to difficult or too easy, but that is just the system gauging your skill.  After you play a handful of games it should place you vs similarly skilled players.

The top 50 players though might not be what you actually think.  Each division has many subdivisions.  So you could be playing vs someone who is top 50 of that subdivision, but that honestly doesn't mean anything.  It could mean that player could be getting close to being promoted to a higher division but it could simply be that they have a lot of games under their belt.  It doesn't mean they are a particularly good player or anything.  My recommendation is that you learn fastest by playing against actual players because it causes you to actually think about your actions and you improve MUCH faster.

TL;DR; If you don't EVER desire to play vs actual human opponents and simply enjoy playing vs computers feel free to continue to do just that.  If you desire to hone your skills for competitive play I would immediately jump in vs actual players.

Comment: I didn't make that top 50 comment. I enjoy playing vs a machine and I was wondering if there was any way to check if it's behaving as expected. I guess it is. My victory streak stopped a while back. :)

Comment: @Zehelvion  You're right, for some reason I thought you said it.  I'll leave that paragraph in with the info with an edit in case anyone finds it useful.